# jQuery, Fancybox - on mouseleave to prevent mouseover function

Tags: jquery, fancybox, mouseleave

this is my 1st question here.

I want to create something like this:
http://www.google.com/think/products/lightbox-ads.html

On mouse over/hover/enter I want to start fancybox lightbox, but only if cursor is in that div for example 2 seconds, but if user move out before that time, it should prevent trigger.

I have write this code, but don't know how to add some clear of timeout or prevent of executing if mouseleave:

```
$('.somediv').fancybox({
                'width': 580,
                'height': 326,
                'autoScale': false,
                'transitionIn': 'elastic',
                'transitionOut': 'elastic',
                'type': 'iframe',
                'fitToView' : false,
                'autoSize' : false,
                'padding':0, 
                'margin':0
            }).mouseover(function (e) {
                $('.gif-loader').show(); // this just showing loading gif...
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
                setTimeout(function() { 
                            $('video.topvideo')[0].pause(); // pausing video on mouseover...
                            $('.somediv').click();
                            $('.gif-loader').hide(); // hides loading gif
                }, 2000).stop(); // 2 seconds
                e.cancelBubble = true;
                return false;
            });
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet is to use the **[hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)** jQuery plugin instead of reinventing the wheel ;)

Then create a function that opens fancybox triggering a `click` on your selector ( `$('.somediv')` as in your example ) like

```
function openFancybox(){
    $(this).trigger("click");
}
```

Then your fancybox and hoverIntent initialization :

```
$('.somediv').fancybox({
    'width': 580,
    'height': 326,
    'autoScale': false, // for v1.3.4
    'transitionIn': 'elastic', // for v1.3.4
    'transitionOut': 'elastic', // for v1.3.4
    'type': 'iframe',
    'fitToView': false, // for v2.1.x
    'autoSize': false, // for v2.1.x
    'padding': 0,
    'margin': 0
}).hoverIntent({
    sensitivity: 7,
    interval:500,
    timeout:0,
    over: openFancybox
 });
```

(Check the hoverIntent's documentation to fine-tune your settings)

Also **notice** that you are mixing API options for fancybox v1.3.4 and v2.1.x that are not compatible with each other (you never mentioned what version you are using) ... I commented them above.

Here is a DEMO http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/mouseEnterLeave_30jul12.html I created for another post (it also closes fancybox on mouseleave though, but you may not need that)

Answer (score 0):

give this a try, set up 2 variables to help track fancybox (fb_timer, fb_showing) and trap the mouseout event:

UPDATE: working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/GpfpK/4/

```
var fb_timer = null;
var fb_showing = false;
$('#gif-loader').hide()
$('#somediv').fancybox({
            'width': 580,
            'height': 326,
            'autoScale': false,
            'transitionIn': 'elastic',
            'transitionOut': 'elastic',
            'type': 'iframe',
            'fitToView' : false,
            'autoSize' : false,
            'padding':0, 
            'margin':0
        }).hover(function (e) {

            $('#gif-loader').show(); // this just showing loading gif...

            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();

            // setup timer 
            fb_timer = setTimeout(function() { 
                        // set fancybox showing
                        fb_showing = true;
                        //\\$('video.topvideo')[0].pause(); // pausing video on mouseover...
                        //\\$('#somediv').trigger("click");
                        $('#gif-loader').hide(); // hides loading gif
            }, 2000); // 2 seconds

            // setup mouse out handler
            // you may need to change "#somediv" to ".fancybox-overlay"
            //$(".fancybox-overlay").mouseout(function() {
            $("#somediv").mouseout(function() {
                console.log("mouseout - hiding loader");
                $('#gif-loader').hide();
                if (fb_showing){
                    // close fancybox
                    $.fancybox.close();
                }else{
                    // stop the timer
                    clearTimeout( fb_timer );
                }
            });    

            e.cancelBubble = true;
            return false;
       });
```

Comment: Thank you for fast replay. For some reason nothing happens on mouseout :/

Comment: i updated my original code to properly separate the hover and mouseout events. here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GpfpK/4/

Comment: Thank you Anthony for your time and effort! If you move cursor before that 2 seconds from div element, trigger will still run :/ I will play now, hope I will make it. Thank you!